# Ruler on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want something like top and left ruler as we have in word that depicts mouse position on ruler, do we have anything in-build on jquery/is there any way to achieve this??

Any UI pro please respond for the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the creation of the ruler elements, say you had a little div inside each ruler that showed the position of the mouse on the relevant axis, with IDs of `mouse-x-pos` and `mouse-y-pos`, respectively, you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').mousemove(function(event) {
        $('#mouse-x-pos').css('left', event.pageX + 'px');
        $('#mouse-y-pos').css('top', event.pageY + 'px');
    });
});
```

I'll leave the CSS to you, the main thing is to use the [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) function with jQuery.

Comment: i knew this thing the issue was with UI thing couldn't understand what to do.. i am damn bad with UI :( thanks for suggestion btw

Comment: Yeah, CSS isn't my strong point either, but chances are it is just a fixed div with a background image and a div or image inside with `position: relative`. Maybe. :-/

Comment: CSS is too confusing :S i always get lost in it... wonder how UI designers manage it

Answer (score 1):

Heres I plugin I wrote which doesn't require Jquery or anything else.
https://github.com/MrFrankel/ruler

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jquery-ui.ruler](https://github.com/efernandesng/jquery-ui.ruler). It is a jquery-ui plugin that creates a top and left ruler.

**Features:**

- units (px, mm, cm, in)
- rules in sub-div's
- ticks spacing/visibility is customizable
- mouse track

**Example:**

```
// simple initialization
$('.selector').ruler();

// or use different unit and tick values
$('.selector').ruler({
    unit: 'mm',
    tickMajor: 10,
    tickMinor: 5,
    tickMicro: 1,
    showLabel: true
});
```